# In Blazor when using the Virtualize component with multiple items per row, is there a way to have items stay horizontally consistent when scrolled?

Tags: blazor, ui-virtualization

I tried to `<Virtualize>` a list of a thousand items showing several per row, with `display: inline-block`. The result in Blazor kinda works, but as the user scrolls, it seems to remove items from the DOM at the beginning and add them at the end in an arbitrary amount, causing the displayed items to change in position unexpectedly, giving the user a bad experience: the items are "reflowed", and an item that used to be in the third position in its row might now be in the first, second, or fourth position in its new row.  The result is that the user scrolls and when a "update" of the items happen, the user loses track of the items that should still be shown in the viewport.

I am indeed using `@key` on the child content of the Virtualize component, and specifying an explicit `ItemSize` on the Virtualize component doesn't seem to help either.

[Demo](https://szalapski.github.io/BlazorRerenderReducers/product-grid-demo): Scroll down slowly and note the items by their six-character hex ID.  After scrolling down a bit but before the first reflow, you'll see the gap for the last item.:

[image: before first reflow]

Then, after scrolling down just a little bit more, the reflow happens.

[image: after first reflow]

Expected behavior: The user should see the same items that were previously near the bottom of the viewport now near the top, in the same horizontal position, with new items following them.

Actual Behavior: The user sees *some* of the same items from before, but in different horizontal locations. Other items are unexpectedly above the viewport.  Thus the user loses perceptual context of where they just scrolled from.

Also, note in the example first screenshot above that the last row before reflow is only partial till it is fully scrolled into view and triggers a rerender/reflow, as if it can't tell that there is room for a few more items.  I suspect this symptom is closely related.

Any ideas on how to coax the Virtualize component into allowing multiple items per row with consistency as scrolling?  I can't believe this is really the designed behavior.  I previously thought I fixed a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71578812/can-i-use-the-virtualize-component-with-multiple-items-per-row), but now I realize that this earlier issue was only part of the problem.

Ideally in a vertical list, it would only add or remove items in the DOM in multiples of the max count of items that fit in a horizontal line. There is no way to tell the Virtualize component this number--only the component could figure it out.

Comment: I would give the @key directive a try.

Comment: The issue facing here is you not providing rows you are providing data that is used in columns/wrap flow. For Virtualize to work it uses a fixed height row and calculates the height of a div that is before and after the visible components. Virtualize does not know your grouping items per row so its not removing 4 at a time which would solve your scroll issue. So Maybe a grouping query to provide a row of 4 items.

Comment: Try giving your `img` elements an explicit height and width.  A big part of the problem on your page is that the image size is only realized after the image is downloaded, causing the virtualize logic to get out of whack.

Comment: You might want to look at the Linq Chunk method. This will give you groupings of N. Let the Virtualize component treat the groups as rows. You may still need a model to put the groups in for @key or you will run back into the other problem.

Comment: @KirkWoll, I have already tried to put a maxHeight on the container `<ul>` and then supplying that number to ItemHeight--it didn't change anything.

Comment: @BrianParker, I'm guessing you are right and I get it, but I don't want to predefine the chunk size, as it will dynamically change with zoom level or window/viewport width.  No way to do this with `<Virtualize>`?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski I thought this may be the issue. This is way outside the intent of the component. If you employ some simple javascript you could get the dimensions of the viewport and calculate the chunk size...

Comment: " This is way outside the intent of the component" - to allow more than one item per row is "way outside"?  Seems like a straightforward need.

Comment: Reflecting further, ideally in a vertical list, it would only add or remove in multiples of the max count of items that fit in a line.  There is no way to tell the Virtualize component that--only the component could figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I beleive the issue you are facing is due to variable height of the rows like others mentioned already into commends. I am facing the same issue in my application where I am listing tables and fields in a master detail view where every table has different set of fields.

The issue of scrolling is also discussed here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25058 where there are already some ideas to have a property for specifying the item height if you can precalculated this so the virtualization knows each element size, instead of fixed size for all elements.

Comment: For me, isn't it also due to the number of items per row being uncertain?  That is, the Virtualize component doesn't know or care how many items are per-row, so it adds/removes arbitrary numbers from the beginning of the collection in the DOM, thus giving the user unexpected shifting of items.  Ideally in a vertical list, it would only add or remove in multiples of the max count of items that fit in a row.

Comment: Seems you are right, I haven't try to populate items also horizontally yet, but it makes sense